# How to loop through a database and print all items in a table

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to create a Servlet that lists all the items of my database table. I want to put the items in a HTML table. So considering what I have so far, could I just add the HTML table layout in my while loop and will it connect to the database and print all items?

```
import java.sql.*;
import database.*;

public class products
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DBConnections dataSource = DBConnections.getInstance();
        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement stat = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        try
        {
            stat = conn.createStatement();
            result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Products");

            string code;
            string item;
            float payment;
            while (result.next())
            {
                proCode = result.get("code");
                item = result.get("item");
                payment = result.geFloat("Payment");
                System.out.println(proCode + "\t" + item + "\t" + payment);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("SQLException in Query.java");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        finally
        {
            DBUtilities.closeResultSet(result);
            DBUtilities.closeStatement(stat);
            dataSource.freeConnection(conn);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The nice and cleaner way to do it is:

Put your database related code and methods in a different class for example `ProductDao` have method in that `productDao.getAllProducts()` that will return `List<Product>` since you are using JDBC you need to map POJO with DB table

Now on Servlet set the list of products in the attribute of request

```
request.setAttribute("productsToDisplay", listOfProducts);
```

forward this request to the JSP which renders the view

on JSP use JSTL to render the products

---

**See**

- [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is locked up in a main method.  What good is that?

Servlets are HTTP listeners.

I think the right way to accomplish what you want is to put the code from your main method (with changes in the way you handle connections) into the servlet.  Then you can issue an HTTP request that tells it to do the database query, format the response into HTML, and stream that back.  Your client will be a browser that will simply render the output stream.

You may not be aware of JSPs and JSTL.  It's the Java Standard Template Library that lets you write dynamic HTML pages as Java Server Pages, which are compiled into servlets for you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, what you've written is kind of correct, but it isn't a servlet.

First you need to base your class on the HttpServlet class

```
public class products extends HttpServlet {
```

then rather than using `main` you use `doGet` or `doPost` to respond to requests

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException {
```

Also see the post from Jigar Joshi on producstDao. Once you have the list you pass it to a s JSP and that will produce the HTML.

A really good book on this is "Head First Servlets and JSP (passing the sun certified web component developer exam)" from O'Reilly

You may also find this useful http://pdf.coreservlets.com/

There is a fairly steep learning curve for this it took me a while to figure it out but once you've got it it works pretty well.